# Import error - what is going on?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python imports. Again...

I have this file structure:

```
[test]
    start.py (from scripts import main)
    [scripts]
        __init__.py (empty)
        main.py (from . import install)
        install.py (from scripts import main # or # from . import main)
```

I get import error:

```
vic@wic:~/projects/test$ python3 start.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scripts import main
  File "/home/vic/projects/test/scripts/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import install
  File "/home/vic/projects/test/scripts/install.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scripts import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
vic@wic:~/projects/test$
```

I don't understand: first time `from scripts import main` worked (by "worked" I mean it didn't fail with `ImportError`), and second time the same code gives `ImportError: cannot import name main`

What is going on?

UPDATE:

My question is not about circular imports. I am confused by the fact that exactly the same code `from scripts import main` first time works ok and then second time fails.

I guess there is some internal import mechanism which i don't understand.

First time a statement imports a module, second time exactly the same code tries to import a name from a module. How this works?

Comment: I'm not an expert about this topic and it's to less for a good answer, but this [link](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/pyporting.html#from-future-import-absolute-import) might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a circular import. You can't do that. Avoid importing `main` from `install`.

What is happening is that a module, while being imported, is incomplete until the whole top level has been executed. If during that execution it imports another module that (directly or indirectly) tries to import the original module again, this will fail. The original module was not yet done importing yet.

In other words, you are creating a circular graph:

```
start -> scripts.main -> scripts.install
              ^                |
              |                |
               ----------------
```

You need to re-arrange your code to not need to import from `main` from within your `scripts` package.

See [What are the “best practices” for using import in a module?](http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-best-practices-for-using-import-in-a-module) for some tips on how to handle this.

Comment: I want the second time to work exactly as it worked the first time, i.e. import `scripts.main` and assign it to name `main`

Comment: >The original module was not yet done importing yet.< Nevertheless, it already is in `sys.modules`, though its importing was not finished

Comment: Yes, but it is *not complete*. Python cannot guarantee that the objects you are trying to import will actually be there or properly defined.

Comment: I understand the issue with circular import, and i won't argue about it. What confuses me is that the same code `from scripts import main` first time is ok and then second time fails

Comment: @warwaruk, the first `from scripts import main` *doesn't* work.  It fails, with an ImportError.  It fails *at the point* when the circularity is first recognized, when the second `from scripts import main` occurs.  I think you're being confused by the fact the traceback shows both imports, but that doesn't mean that it made it successfully through the first one: it's *in the process* of trying to do that first one that it executes the lines shown and fails.

Comment: @warwaruk: Your first import doesn't succeed; it fails while the main module is being imported due to a circular import that cannot be resolved.

Comment: Right before the exception happens i do `pprint.pprint(sys.modules)` and find 'scripts', 'scripts.install' and 'scripts.main'. When i say that first `from scripts import main` works, i don't mean it finished importing, i mean it doesn't fail with 'ImportError: cannot import name main'. I had a guess of what is happening, but wanted to confirm asking the question on SO.

Comment: My guess was this:
When it executes `from scripts import main` first time, Python sees that `scripts` is not in `sys.modules` and treats `main` as a module name, importing first `scripts` and then `scripts.main`. My guess is that when Python meets `from scripts import main` second time it sees that `scripts` module is already imported and treats `main` as a simple object name that should exist in module `scripts`.
Is there a logic in what in what i wrote?

Comment: @warwaruk: Nope. Python treats `import scripts.main` the same as `from scripts import main`. `scripts` is recognized as a package (a directory with a `__init__.py` thus python will always first see if there is a `main` object defined for that package, then fall back to looking for a module. See http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages. It makes no difference if there already is an entry in sys.modules.

Answer (score 3):

`main` imports `install` and `install` imports `main`:

- `from scripts import main` in `start.py` leads to
- `from . import install` in `main.py`  leads to
- `from scripts import main` in `install.py` -- circular import

To solve the circular import either combine `main` and `install` into a single module or create the 3rd module that both modules can import.

Comment: @warwaruk: I've spelled out the sequence explicitly. `from scripts import main` *doesn't* work the first time because it never completes in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

start.py:

```
from scripts import main
```

scripts/main.py:

```
import install
```

scripts/install.py:

```
import main
```

Comment: This is not the same situation as mine. I try to import a module from a package, not a name from another module

Answer (score 0):

This is a patch I use to override the default behavior:

```
import sys
import builtins
import importlib

def _import(name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=None, level=0, __import__=__import__):
    """A hack to to make names of imported modules to be available in the parent package before
    they are fully imported. If a module is present in sys.modules event if it's not fully
    imported, it should not be a problem.
    I.e. ``from package import module1, module2`` will create variables ``package.module1`` and
    ``package.module2`` at start of the import, not when it's finished.
    This helps in some situations with circular import.
    """
    module = __import__(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
    for attr in fromlist or ():
        sub_module = sys.modules.get(module.__name__ + '.' + attr)
        if sub_module:  # is this a module?
            # if subpackage is already being imported, even if not finished,
            # inject its name into the parent package
            setattr(module, attr, sub_module)
    return module

builtins.__import__ = _import
```

Here is a project to test this: https://github.com/warvariuc/python_import_improver