# Python circular import, `from lib import module` vs `import lib.module`

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I have two python modules, `a.py` and `b.py`, both of which are in `lib/` relative to the current directory. Suppose each module needs the functionality of the other.

**a.py:**

```
import lib.b
...
```

**b.py:**

```
import lib.a
...
```

The above example works with

```
PYTHONPATH=./lib python -c 'from lib import a, b'
```

However, if I switch the imports in `a.py` and `b.py` to `from lib import b` and `from lib import a`, respectively, the above Python command terminates with `ImportError`.

Could someone please explain why this breaks? I'm not trying to import any member from either `a` or `b`. (In that case I would be importing from an uninitialized module, as the question referenced below points out.)

#### Reference:

1. [python circular imports once again (aka what's wrong with this design)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955790/python-circular-imports-once-again-aka-whats-wrong-with-this-design)

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974395/import-error-what-is-going-on/

Comment: -1 -- "works" and "breaks" don't have a meaning. Please specify what do you mean by providing a runnable example that demonstrates the behaviour. Also, if you get an error, you should post *all* the output you get and if you get an unexpected result you should post both the expected and actual result you get.

Comment: +1: I can reproduce the issue. @Bakuriu: run [`test_from_vs_import.py`](https://github.com/zed/circular-import-vs-from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there did not seem to be a direct way to address the circular import, I went with a workaround.

In my actual use case, module `a` imported module `b` only to call the function `b.fn`, so I decided to put `fn` in a third module `c` and import `c` instead:

#### c.py

```
def fn():
  ...
```

#### b.py

```
from lib import a
from lib import c
...
# Explicitly assign `fn` into this module.
fn = c.fn
```

(The above could also be done with `from lib.c import fn`, but I prefer the explicit version.)

#### a.py

```
from lib import c
...
```

That way, the circular import between `a` and `b` is gone, and any additional modules that import `b` can use `b.fn` directly.

Answer (score 0):

in your lib folder there is a __init__.py file?
If yes you have 2 possibility:

1) __init__.py is empty and you can use from lib import a,b

a.foo b.bar

2) in your __init__.py there are istructions import a,b in this case you can write

import lib.a as a
import lib.b as b

hope this help you

Comment: It is incorrect. [Empty `__init__.py` does not help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397610/python-circular-import-from-lib-import-module-vs-import-lib-module#comment34067749_22397610)

Comment: `lib/__init_py` is empty. I can import `a` and `b` in this file, but it doesn't help with the circular import problem. Moreover, I'd like to avoid adding every package under `lib/` to `lib/__init__.py`.